# How to create a BSpline or polyfit graph where the x values are datetime objects?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, matplotlib, bspline

So for a school project I am designing a program that creates a graph of tide heights over time. BSpline doesn't take in datetime objects, and neither does np.linspace which from what I have seen is necessary for BSpline to run.

I have tried using pandas to convert the datetime to a value np can read, or using datetime64. In the code below I have removed all my failed methods and just left the bare bones.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, datestr2num
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline,BSpline

test_xvals = [datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 28), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 47), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 13, 7), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 20, 43)]  #times which correspond to the height of the tides
test_yvals =  [3.3, 3.9, 0.8, 4.5] #height of the tides in meters

times = date2num(test_xvals) #converts to object compatible with numpy and matplotlib
heights = np.array(test_yvals) #array of 4 floats

x_smooth = np.linspace(times.min(), times.max(), 300)
spl = make_interp_spline(times,heights , k=3) #BSpline object
y_smooth = spl(x_smooth)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_smooth, y_smooth)
ax.scatter(times,heights)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
#pyplot.xticks(dates,xlabels)
pyplot.ylim(0,6)
```

The sine graph does not match the data points. What attributes of BSpline should I tweak to make the data points match up with local max/mins?
[Graph with out of sync data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tnk2.png)

Comment: Do you expect us to guess where the error occurs?

Comment: Sorry! Updated it.

Comment: Reread the `BSpline` docs.

Comment: Rereading the BSpline docs was not helpful, but I finally found a stack overflow question that answered a similar issue and got my graph to curve. However, those curves do not line up with the actual data points (I updated the code and included a picture of the output). How can I fix that?

Comment: The thing that stood out to  me was that third argument, `k`, is supposed to be a single number.  You gave it an array, from linspace.

Comment: Yes I set ````k = 3````